# Filesystem saves all filename with the same time

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript program with filesystem (saves user answer,etc)                The file name I have implemented data and time however if the user repeats the program, and after that ends it. All the file will be saved with the same time

Tried putting it into a string. After the file system does it job, i clears the string.  Which is suppose to work? because it will check for new local time.

```
function filesystem() {
    var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();   //gets local machine year,date,time.
    var time = today.getHours() + "Hour." + today.getMinutes() + " Min." + today.getSeconds() + " Seconds";
    var dateTime = parseFloat("Date " + date + ' ' + "Time " + time);
    var dateTimestr= "";
    dateTimestr += (dateTime);
    fs.writeFile("CA2/Quizresults/" + fullname + " " + categorystorage + " " + dateTimestr + ".txt", summarystring + "Your score is " + point + "/5.", (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    })
    console.log('Saved!');                           //when saved successfully. it will prompt the user.
    point = 0;                                       //Sets point as 0. so the point does not bring forward to the next user.
    lifelinecounter = 0;                             //Sets lifelinecounter as 0. so the lifelinecounter does not bring forward to the next user.
    summarystring = "";   
    dateTimestr ="";                           //Sets summarystring as empty. so the summarystring does not bring forward to the next user.
}
```

All the files saves with the same time in the file name

Comment: I guess `today` equals to `new Date()`, if so, Check if the `today` is reassigned with every execution of the function.

Comment: var today = new Date();

Comment: I guess today equals to new Date(), if so, Check if the today is reassigned with every execution of the function.     sorry new to javascript. can you explain?

Comment: i have fixed it. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
var today = new Date();
```

Please add the above as the first statement of the function. You have assigned *today* outside the function, and it's value is not going to change according to the running time. If you want current date, you will have to call **new Date()** again and assign it to your today variable.

Answer (score 0):

So you bound the `today` variable to a `new Date()`

```
var today = new Date() // right?
```

now when `filesystem` function runs, it's looking at that variable, and that variable holds the same value forever from the moment when you initialize it.
So you need to reassign value at the beginning of the function like this:

```
 function filesystem() {
    today = new Date()
    var date = today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + today.getDate();   //gets local machine year,date,time.
    var time = today.getHours() + "Hour." + today.getMinutes() + " Min." + today.getSeconds() + " Seconds";
    var dateTime = parseFloat("Date " + date + ' ' + "Time " + time);
    var dateTimestr= "";
    dateTimestr += (dateTime);
    fs.writeFile("CA2/Quizresults/" + fullname + " " + categorystorage + " " + dateTimestr + ".txt", summarystring + "Your score is " + point + "/5.", (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    })
    console.log('Saved!');                           //when saved successfully. it will prompt the user.
    point = 0;                                       //Sets point as 0. so the point does not bring forward to the next user.
    lifelinecounter = 0;                             //Sets lifelinecounter as 0. so the lifelinecounter does not bring forward to the next user.
    summarystring = "";   
    dateTimestr ="";                           //Sets summarystring as empty. so the summarystring does not bring forward to the next user.
}
```